# Windows 10 delay autologin

Tags: windows, login

I currently have 2 users on my PC, and I need one of those users to log in automatically after X seconds. This is possible? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean that if nobody logs in manually after x seconds, to automatically login that user?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I need.